# Android - Firebase .orderByChild() not working in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase

Currently I have a `FirebaseRecyclerView` and I am trying to order each item based on how many views it has. Each item contains the child `views` which stores how many views it has. In the adapter, when calling `firebase.orderByChild("views")` it does not order the list based on the views. Here's my code.

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<HashMap,recyclerViewHolder > adapter1 = 
    new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<HashMap, recyclerViewHolder>
    (HashMap.class, R.layout.list_item, recyclerViewHolder.class,
    firebase.orderByChild("views")) {
       // .... Code goes here
}
```

The data in the dashboard looks like this:

```
yournews
    items
        -FHUUOOKJJSUuUFBu
            views: 5
        -KEDUEdhsuRIUAFAS
            views: 7
```

When the code runs, no matter how many views each item has, the order does not change in the `RecyclerView`

I have a feeling I am going about this all wrong. Can anyone tell me why this isn't working?

Is is that the `firebase` variable is set to `MYFIREBASE.firebaseio.com/items`? Each item has a key with the children inside, to the `views` for each item is stored in `MYFIREBASE.firebaseio.com/items/itemkey/views`

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Initially I think you need to get the reference to this `MYFIREBASE.firebaseio.com/items/itemkey/`. But anyway, in case of any firebase question, you really need to post some of your example data in JSON format in the question to get faster response.

Comment: @ReazMurshed I am adding multiple items to the RecyclerView so cannot change the Firebase reference to a specific key.

Comment: Post your sample json data please

Comment: Can you post some sample data and what you are getting in response after `orderByChild()` ?

Comment: Added some sample data